# QuickTime video grabber example for Windows

Tags: wpf, windows, quicktime

Do you know some *working* example of how to grab frames from video using QuickTime on Windows? I need to play the video in memory and access every rendered frame pixel by pixel. My app is WPF calling dll code from C++ library.

I have some old code using SetMovieDrawingCompleteProc and accessing the rendered frames using GetGWorldPixMap. But there are some memory leaks and also the code stops working sometimes by unhanded exception inside Quicktime - and I can't make it work correctly.

This is the grab code:

```
    CGrafPtr pOldWorld = nil;
    GDHandle pOldHandle = nil;
    GetGWorld(&pOldWorld, &pOldHandle);
    SetGWorld(m_offscreenWorld, NULL);

    PixMapHandle pixMapHandle = GetGWorldPixMap(m_offscreenWorld);

    SetGWorld(pOldWorld, pOldHandle);

    if (!LockPixels(pixMapHandle))
        return;

    UCHAR *pixBaseAddr = (UCHAR*)GetPixBaseAddr(pixMapHandle);

    // handle pixels...

    UnlockPixels(pixMapHandle);

    SetGWorld(pOldWorld, pOldHandle);
```

This is how I open the movie:

```
    qtErr = FSMakeFSSpec(0, 0, macFullPath, &m_sfFile);
    if (qtErr != noErr)
        throw "Can't convert filename to mac file struct";

    qtErr = OpenMovieFile(&m_sfFile, &theFile, fsRdPerm);
    if (qtErr != noErr)
        throw "Can't open file";


    qtErr = NewMovieFromFile(&m_movie, theFile, nil, nil, 0, nil);
    if (qtErr != noErr)
    {
        m_movie = nil;
        throw "Can't make new movie";
    }

    qtErr = CloseMovieFile(theFile);
    if (qtErr != noErr)
        throw "Can't close movie";

    SetMovieActive(m_movie, true);

    GetMovieBox(m_movie, &m_movieRect);

    qtErr = QTNewGWorld(
        &m_offscreenWorld, k32BGRAPixelFormat, &m_movieRect,
        NULL, NULL, NULL);
    if (qtErr != noErr)
        throw "Can't create off screen world";

    CGrafPtr pOldWorld = nil;
    GDHandle pOldHandle = nil;
    GetGWorld(&pOldWorld, &pOldHandle);
    SetGWorld(m_offscreenWorld, NULL);

    SetMovieGWorld(m_movie, m_offscreenWorld, NULL);

    SetGWorld(pOldWorld, pOldHandle);

    m_movieController = NewMovieController(m_movie,
        &m_movieRect, mcNotVisible | mcScaleMovieToFit | mcTopLeftMovie);
    if (m_movieController == nil)
        throw "Can't get movie controller";

    SetMovieDrawingCompleteProc(
        m_movie, movieDrawingCallWhenChanged,
        pContext->drawCompleteFunc, (long)this);
```

Before you any suggestions of using DirectShow, DirectX, some Windows media stuff - no, I can't use it, since I need precise speed control of the video (and no, it's not working well in these technologies).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately QuickTime is not supported on Windows 10 anymore and it doesn't work good there indeed. Especially when you try to play multiple mov files at once. So no example required anymore :) ...